# Get the changed file list list with line numbers from svn, start revision and end revision is given

Tags: java, svn, sdk, tortoisesvn, gosu

Say you have a begin revision number and end revision number of SVN, Is there any SDK api in java to get the changed file list list with line numbers change is made? I am using the TortoiseSVN. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple

```
svn diff -r start_rev:end_rev
```

It will give you all the information between these two revision that include the change in the middle of them...

Are you looking for something that gives you details of changes between all the revisions in the range?